# submit button that will update oracle db

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle, user-interface, datagridview

I have a GUI that gives the user the ability to input five entries into a datagridview. After that, they would click the "Submit" button that will go into the oracle database and update the entries into its respective modules. I have done the code for the GUI -- very simple. But how should I start this connection with oracle?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download and install the Oracle ODP.NET connector. Dont use the oracle connector in .NET libraries, its not supported and recommended to use Oracle's.
2. Find Oracle.DataAccess.dll and reference it in your project.
3. Add a namespace `using` at the top of the file for ease of use.
4. Look up the docs from mircosoft on how to use the standard ADO.NET interfaces. IIRC, the MSDN docs are better than the Oracle docs. Use the OracleConnection and OracleCommand classes for Sql execution.

If your solution requires much data being updated or retrieved, consider using the OracleDataAdapter with a DataSet.
There are plenty of tutorials for using all these different classes.